# Accessing object in json from php

Tags: php, json, object

It's been a while since I've done this, and I'm clearly missing some critical piece. I hope one you all can set me straight.

I have a json file that I'm decoding and I was hoping it was a simple task to access the data for a specific date. Here's what I've done so far.

```
$solardata = file_get_contents('solar.json');
$solarjson = json_decode("$solardata");
$production = $solarjson->{'2019-01-24 11:00:00'};
echo "$production";
```

The $production variable is always empty.
For reference the solar.json file starts out like this:

```
{"powerDetails":{"timeUnit":"QUARTER_OF_AN_HOUR","unit":"W","meters":[{"type":"Production","values":[{"date":"2019-01-24 11:00:00","value":273.5632},{"date":"2019-01-24 11:15:00","value":405.8625},{"date":"2019-01-24 11:30:00","value":558.6771},
```

A var_dump($solarjson) starts out like this:

```
object(stdClass)#321 (1) { ["powerDetails"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["timeUnit"]=> string(18) "QUARTER_OF_AN_HOUR" ["unit"]=> string(1) "W" ["meters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["type"]=> string(10) "Production" ["values"]=> array(316) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2019-01-24 11:00:00" ["value"]=> float(273.5632) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2019-01-24 11:15:00" ["value"]=> float(405.8625) } [2]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2019-01-24 11:30:00" ["value"]=> float(558.6771) }
```

The server error log says:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$2019-01-24 11:00:00 in /home/......
```

Are the ojects I'm trying to access inside an array that I still need to loop through? I was dreaming that I could avoid all that with a simple object request, as I look for specific data, but as I said, I'm pretty rusty.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: look at your data and think for a second. then you'll see that '2019-01-24 11:00:00' is **not an existing key**, but a value.

Comment: I did think for several minutes before posting, and I guess I'm misunderstanding the data. Hence the question. I somehow thought from looking at the data that the timestamp was the key and the value attached to each stampstamp was the value. 
I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

```
$solardata = file_get_contents('solar.json');
$solarjson = json_decode("$solardata");
$production = $solarjson['powerDetails']['meters'][0]['values']['date'];
echo "$production";`
```

this OUTPUT '2019-01-24 11:00:00';

You may also modify the content by :

```
$solardata = file_get_contents('solar.json');
$solarjson = json_decode("$solardata");
$solarjson['powerDetails']['meters'][0]['values']['date'] = date(y-m-d);
echo $solarjson['powerDetails']['meters'][0]['values']['date'];`
```

Comment: Am I correct to understand that for that array to work as expected, I'd need to modify my json_decode request to return an array (adding TRUE)? My first attempts at that are not working.
Since the data is a large set of timestamps and their corresponding power values, my goal here is to retrieve the power value associated with certain timestamps - ie I'm looking for the power value associated with that '2019-01-24 11:00:00' entry (which I thought was a key but other comments say it is not).

Comment: Hi dear
First you have a number of overlapping Array

Comment: This is the correct form of data format

`{
"powerDetails":{
"timeUnit":"QUARTER_OF_AN_HOUR",
"unit":"W",
"meters":[
{
"type":"Production",
"values":[
{
"date":"2019-01-24 11:00:00",
"value":273.5632
},
{
"date":"2019-01-24 11:15:00",
"value":405.8625
},
{
"date":"2019-01-24 11:30:00",
"value":558.6771
}
]
}
]
}
}`

Comment: `foreach($solarjson['powerDetails']['meters'] AS $dt){
   echo $dt['values']['date'];
   echo $dt['values']['value'];
}`

This is a way to read the data if the organization is correct, but your data is wrong in the wording

Comment: I really appreciate the detail in your reply, but I'm still struggling to make sense of this. I've done 2 things.
1) I changed the json_decode line so that it outputs as an array
2) I compared my json code to your example of the correct format, and they appear identical - except my example was just the beginning of the file, so it doesn't show the closing brackets and braces - but they are there.
So I can't tell where my data is formatted wrongly.
Your lovely code example generates server errors that say "Undefined index: date" and "value", so my foreach array expression is still be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I had already added the TRUE to make the result an array, but I'm still without success.